# An abstract class cannot be instantiated in module

Tags: class, module, system-verilog, new-operator, uvm

I am seeing following error while trying to instantiate a new() function.

Error-[SV-ACCNBI] An abstract class cannot be instantiated
model_dpi_module, "umc_uvc_ptr = new("umc_uvc_ptr", null);"
Instantiation of the object 'umc_uvc_ptr' can not be done because its type
'uvm_component' is an abstract base class.
Perhaps there is a derived class that should be used.

Code is as follows:

```
  module model_dpi_module
  task abc_model_dpi(int pkg,int inst);
  uvm_component umc_uvc_ptr;
  **umc_uvc_ptr = new("umc_uvc_ptr", null);**
  umc_uvc_ptr = uvm_top.find($sformatf("uvm_test_top.example_uvc.export_uvc_%0d_%0d_%0d", 0, inst,  inst));
  umc_uvc[pkg][inst].if_env[0].run_model_init(0, 0,0);
 endtask : abc_model_dpi
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Being in a module has nothing to do with it. You cannot construct (call `new`)  on an instance of `uvm_component`. It is meaningless.

You do not need to construct anything as the next line is going to put a handle into `umc_uvc_ptr` anyways. Simply remove the line that is giving you an error.

Comment: yes, but for every transaction umc_uvc_ptr should have a new  instantiation..

Comment: Should uvm_top.find() return a different handle each time it's called with different arguments?

Comment: yes.. inst will change from 0-15

Comment: Then there is no need to construct a class instance here. You want the  class instance that `find()` returns.